# Css boxes centering like ios home screen

Tags: html, css

how do i get this result without the last item in row:

```
margin-right: 30px;
```

in css, now i use:

```
margin-right:                                                   30px;
margin-bottom:                                                  30px;
```

it should be like the ios home screen

http://www4.picturepush.com/photo/a/12640862/img/12640862.png
http://www3.picturepush.com/photo/a/12640866/img/12640866.png

html:

```
<div class="home-main">
        <a href="t1home" class="item"><h1>Hallo</h1></a>
        <a href="t1home" class="item"><h1>Hallo</h1></a>
        <a href="t1home" class="item"><h1>Hallo</h1></a>
        <a href="t1home" class="item"><h1>Hallo</h1></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
 .home-main {
    width:                                                          90%;
    max-width:                                                      960px;
    min-height:                                                     100px;
    margin:                                                         0 auto;
    overflow:                                                       hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.home-main a {
    width:                                                          126px;
    min-height:                                                     126px;
    max-height:                                                     166px;
    margin-right:                                                   30px;
    margin-bottom:                                                  30px;
    background-color:                                               #777;
    float:                                                          left;
    color:                                                          #fff;
    text-decoration:                                                none;
}
.home-main a:nth-last-child(1){
    margin-right:                                                   0;
}
.home-main a h1 {
    width:                                                          100%;
    height:                                                         33px;
    margin:                                                         0;
    margin-top:                                                     126px;
    padding-top:                                                    7px;
    font-size:                                                      19px;
    text-align:                                                     center;
    background-color:                                               #222;
}
@media screen and (width:320px){
    .home-main a:nth-child(even) {
        margin-right:                                               0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This depends on your HTML and other CSS, what have you tried?  Please provide more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will demo something done with JavaScript, as that is default on iOS. I only used jQuery to switch the ready-state for the document, but you can add that to the body-tag too. After that you won't need jQuery per se.

What I'm doing with JavaScript is add extra to the `left-padding` based on the division of the remainder of the space that is still open so it will push the floats to the horizontal middle.

I'll delete the answer if JavaScript is an issue.

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/xQegJ/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="floatClear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
}

.block {
    width: 130px;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: grey;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.floatClear {
    clear: both;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

    var wrap_w = wrapper.offsetWidth - (5*2); // minus padding
    var block_w = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].offsetWidth + (5*2); // plus margin

    var remainder = wrap_w % block_w;
    var left_add = Math.floor(remainder / 2); // what to add left

    wrapper.style.paddingLeft = (left_add + 5) + 'px';

    //console.log(remainder);
});
```

Good luck!